# FullCalendar: Convert date format in PHP

Tags: php, date, fullcalendar

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ I want to create an event on my server when the select function is called.

This is my code:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/account/availability",
            data: {action: "create", start: start, end: start},
            success: function(id) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
                    title: "My Event",
                    start: start,
                    end: end,
                    allDay: true,
                    id: id
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is, that the dates of start and end are in a weired format, like this "Thu Jan 09 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)". How can I convert that format into a php, so that I can save these events easily into my database?

Comment: How do you know that the date format? Do you maybe use some output function that pretty prints it in your locale?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [strtotime](http://pt2.php.net/strtotime), some times strtotime will not work in strings with some locations like this one, so make sure you clean your values, in this example i used explode.

```
$date = 'Thu Jan 09 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Zeit)';

    $time = strtotime(current(explode("(",$date)));

echo Date('Y / M / d', $time);
```

Working example here: [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IgFlZG)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same kind of problem but in `javaScript`. But I used the fullCalander built-in function to that.

```
var dd = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,"yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Check my SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199066/convert-this-kind-of-date-format-tue-mar-04-2014-000000-gmt0530-sri-lanka-s).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so using [fullcalendar convert date function](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/formatDate/)

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {

    //$.fullCalendar.formatDate( date, formatString [, options ] ) -> String
    // Notice that i used the variable assign to calendar var
    // var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ .....

    var startDate = calendar.formatDate( start, "yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    var endDate = calendar.formatDate( end, "yyyy-MM-dd");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/account/availability",
        data: {action: "create", start: start, end: start},
        success: function(id) {
            calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',{
                title: "My Event",
                start: start,
                end: end,
                allDay: true,
                id: id
            });
        }
    });
}
```