# Convert this kind of date format [Tue Mar 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time) ] to Java Date Object

Tags: java, javascript, date, fullcalendar

I'm using Jquery [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) and It has a method to be called when a date cell event click.

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) 
{
    if (allDay)
    {
        alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
    }else
    {
        alert('Clicked on the slot: ' + date);
    }
}
```

It's kinda like above. But the date it prints or it has in `date` is like this.
`Tue Mar 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)`

How can I convert this kinda formatted string to a Java Date object. 
When i parse it it will through a `parseException`.
I need to get a  Java Date object which has the format of `yyyy-MM-dd`

**Updated :**
Basically I need to convert a date string of format 
`Tue Mar 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)`
To a Java Date object. (specifically in format `yyyy-MM-dd`)

Comment: Java != JavaScript.  You usually cannot create a *Java* date object in *JavaScript* code.

Comment: var dd = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,"yyyy-MM-dd");

Answer (score 0):

Basically I wanted to change the format of the FullCalendar `date` object. 
I achieved that by the following.

The `date` has the following format by default. `Tue Mar 04 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (Sri Lanka Standard Time)`

```
var dd = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,"yyyy-MM-dd");
```